# Setting useragent in PHP file_get_contents?

Tags: php, regex, mobile

I am trying to get the content from a page using file_get_contents to get the HTML and regex for further processing.

The site I am getting my content from has a desktop and mobile site so I was wondering is there a way to send a custom useragent to get the mobile site instead of the desktop site?

Using file_get_contents I have tried it with my code shown below but all I get is a blank page:

```
$options = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU iPad OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X; en-us)   AppleWebKit/535.1+ (KHTML like Gecko) Version/7.2.0.0 Safari/6533.18.5\r\n" // i.e. An iPad )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/api/'.$atrib,false,$context);
$doc = new DOMDocument();// create new dom document

$doc->loadHTML($file);// load the xmlpage 

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('video'); // find the tag we are looking for

foreach ($tags as $tag) { // for ever tag that is the same make it a new tag of its own

    if (isset($_GET['key']) && $_GET['key'] == $key) { // if key is in url and matches script key - do or dont

    echo $tag->getAttribute('src'); // get out 3 min video from the attribute in page

    } else { // if key is not in url or not correct show error

        echo "ACCESS DENIED!"; // our out bound error

    }

}
```

I am trying to get the useragent to load up the content from the sites mobile page and useing regex get the src url from this line of code in the page just in case this is the problem:

`<video id="player" src="http://example.com/api/4.m3u8" poster="http://example.com/default.png" autoplay="" autobuffer="" preload="" controls="" height="537" width="935"></video>`

Comment: At the end of the line `"User-Agent: Mozilla...` the closing parenthesis is commented. Please use `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: thanks i fixed it now al seems to b e working ok

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) in the comments, uncomment the closing parenthesis at the end of the line of `"User-Agent: Mozilla...`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```